# Not able to target 2nd matching element by XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a html content like this

```
<div class="ng-star-inserted">
  <span class="ng-star-inserted">
    <a href="#/users/roledetail/875">Seismic interpreter</a>
  </span>
  <span class="ng-star-inserted">
    <a href="#/users/roledetail/876">Geophysicist</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

I have a selenium script where I am trying to get the first role name and second role name.
I tried this, but it's not giving me the 1st and 2nd elements as expected. Any idea what am I missing? thanks!

```
'//div[@class="ng-star-inserted"]//span//a[1]'
'//div[@class="ng-star-inserted"]//span//a[2]'
```

[image: Xpath tries]

Answer (score 2):

You can xpath indexing in this case :

so instead of this  :

```
'//div[@class="ng-star-inserted"]//span//a[1]'
'//div[@class="ng-star-inserted"]//span//a[2]'
```

use this :

```
"(//div[@class='ng-star-inserted']//span//a)[1]"
"(//div[@class='ng-star-inserted']//span//a)[2]"
```

or if you think the text won't change, you can make use of `LINK_TEXT` as well or `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`

Sample code  :-

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
button1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Seismic interpreter")))
button1.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the below way

```
((//a[contains(text(),'Seismic interpreter')])[2])
((//a[contains(text(),'Geophysicist')])[2])

clickLink=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"((//a[contains(text(),'Seismic interpreter')])[2])")))
checkbox.click()
```